# Where do I initialise the props values when using redux without having my props leaking into the redux side of things

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I am a bit confused with where is the best place to initialise state values in the following case.

The fields are dynamic as based on the user input, I changes the label and the error message and the input style by adding a border.

Should I initialise the props in the container where I do mapStateToProps, or it must be initialised in the reducer?

How do I initialise without having my props leaking into the redux side of things and How do I read the initialValues prop provided by connect()?

Can I have an example please?

I have interface as follows:

```
    export interface IFormField {
    Label: string,
    Name: string,
    ErrorMessage: string,
    Text: string
  }

  export interface ILogInProps {
    FirstName: IFormField,
    Password: IFormField,
    Email: IFormField,
    Fetching: boolean,
    Message?: string
  }
```

---

LogIn.tsx

```
interface IProps{ 
  onChange: (fieldName: string, value: string) => any;
  FirstName: IFormField
  LastName: IFormField
  Email:IFormField
}

export class UserForm extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {    
    const { FirstName, Password, Email} = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
      <Field name={FirstName.Name} label={FirstName.Label} value={FirstName.Text} ErrorMessage={FirstName.ErrorMessage} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
      <Field name={Password.Name} label={Password.Label} value={Password.Text}  ErrorMessage={Password.ErrorMessage} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
      <Field name={Email.Name} label={Email.Label} value={Password.Text}  ErrorMessage={Password.ErrorMessage} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the first name, password, email? You have declared them in the correct place. Just make sure to pass them down to your User form component from the parent like this, <UserForm FirstName={firtsname} etc... />

Comment: @Lloyd: I haven`t initialised anything yet.  I meant where to I initialise the initial values: e.g FirstName.Name = ''nom"  FirstName.Label='Nom"

Comment: the values will be set in your reducer.

Comment: @Lloyd can I have an example please